# With a Reg. Exp. in JS, Check for 2 Strings Within A String

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I'm rubbish at regular expressions, so would someone be able to help me find:

`In a string` at least one occurrence of `of two other strings`.

For example looking for the strings `foo` and `bar`:

`foo foo bar`: true

`bar`: false

`foo bar`: true

`foo barfoo`: true

`foobar bar`: true

`foo ba`: false

`foo foo bar bar`: true

Thank you all in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/^(?=.*foo)(?=.*bar).*$/.test("foo bar");
```

and if you want to match whole words and not fragments :

```
/^(?=.*\bfoo\b)(?=.*\bbar\b).*$/.test("foo bar");
```

Comment: As always, that's so close to what I had! Thank you!